# How to configure Gnome 3 on Ubuntu-19.04 Virtual Machine running on my Google Cloud Platform?

Tags: gnome, virtualization, gnome-shell, remote-desktop, 19.04

I am able to follow these links to configure **Gnome 2** onto my VM in GCP successfully.
[Installing and configuring Ubuntu Desktop for Google Cloud Platform](https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781788474221/1/ch01lvl1sec15/installing-and-configuring-ubuntu-desktop-for-google-cloud-platform)

[Graphical user interface (GUI) for Google Compute Engine instance](https://medium.com/google-cloud/graphical-user-interface-gui-for-google-compute-engine-instance-78fccda09e5c)

I am using Remmina on my ubuntu-19.04 on my local pc to establish a VNC connection to the VM on google cloud which is running a **tighvncserver**.

This is how my present desktop (inside Google Cloud Platform VM) looks like. [GNOME 2 Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yljrS.jpg)
**I want it to look like Gnome 3 Desktop like the one which shippes with Ubuntu 19.04.**

We are required to edit the `~/.vnc/xstartup` script for the VNC session to work properly as described in the links above. But these configurations are old enough and using `metacity` which renders a Gnome2 session.

How to run a Gnome 3 (complete desktop experience) on my Google Cloud Virtual Machine which looks and feels exactly like **Ubuntu 19.04**.

**What changes do I need to make to the `~/.vnc/xstartup` script to be able to render a Gnome 3.32(the one in Ubuntu 19.04 desktop) session?**

Comment: gnome 2 uses GTK+2  (from 2010 or before), so I think you're referring to GNOME-Classic (which is still gnome3; just without gnome-shell) and calling it gnome2 which I find confusing.  (https://help.gnome.org/users/gnome-help/stable/gnome-classic.html)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. What I meant is the Gnome shell 3.32 which is running in Ubuntu 19.04. The cool looking modern desktop Interface.