# How can I create a virtual machine on GCP with Dekstop GUI (to use Google Chrome browser) WITHOUT using a remote connection?

Tags: 20.04, google-chrome, virtualization, desktop-environments

I tried this:
[How to configure Gnome 3 on Ubuntu-19.04 Virtual Machine running on my Google Cloud Platform?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1141455/how-to-configure-gnome-3-on-ubuntu-19-04-virtual-machine-running-on-my-google-cl)

Among many many other threads to figure this one out. But these require a virtual/remote desktop. Also I'm completely new to Ubuntu and many of the answers don't refer to more basic methods.

Ultimate goal: My work recently blocked a particular website (https://mlm.pearson.com/) and will not unblock it; I need access to this website to do homework. I DO NOT need/want any input about doing homework at work. If you can think of another way to accomplish this, please give ideas. I can confirm that using "testing" websites such as https://app.lambdatest.com/console/realtime works. However, they only offer 10 minutes at a time and I don't think I'm using it in the way they want.

Current solution: I want to run Google Chrome Browser using Google Cloud Platform. ONLY using the f1 instance (as this is free as long as I don't abuse it). I don't care about the platform (unbuntu, debian etc), I just need google chrome to work 100% (as if on windows 10). However, I think unbuntu is the best choice.

Problem: I'm able to get a GCP f1 instance running Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS (GNU/Linux 5.4.0-1034-gcp x86_64). But I can't figure out how to launch Google Chrome.

As I understand it, Ubuntu is the OS right? But I need a GUI correct? Or is there a way to launch a Google Chrome browser without a desktop GUI? From everything I've seen so far I can't launch a browser without a desktop GUI. So, I'm stuck at trying to launch a desktop.

I've tried MANY methods (basically the top 30 returns when I search on the internet) to install a desktop GUI (using "tasksel" and "sudo tasksel" command), but I keep running into this error (if I don't use sudo)

```
debconf: DbDriver "passwords" warning: could not open /var/cache/debconf/passwords.dat: Permission denied
debconf: DbDriver "config": could not write /var/cache/debconf/config.dat-new: Permission denied
tasksel: debconf failed to run
```

When I google about this, they say I need to "log in" via CTRL + ALT + F1, but when I do hit that combo, nothing happens. I'm assuming this has something to do with the the fact that GCP is supposed to be a server only? Or somehow my keyboard command isn't going through? I found a few documents online about how to use a "remote" method to log into the desktop, but I can't install anything on my computer at work and downloading an .exe file is also risky (NOT ideal). So remoting in (unless there is a web browser version) is also not ideal.

If I do use sudo I get this error

```
xserver-xorg                                    install
tasksel: apt-get failed (100)
```

So. How can I use GCP to launch a virtual Ubuntu desktop (to ultimately launch google chrome to access that website)? Thank you. Some pictures to help understand whats going on:

I can get to the "tasksel" menu, but it doesn't work
[image]
And these are my results
[image]

Comment: So you have a headless server that you want to get a GUI running on so you can use a browser remotely, correct?

Comment: I think the answer to your question is yes. 
I'm not exactly sure what "headless" means.. But I just want to access google chrome using the GCP option. If thats available. Without installing or downloading any 3rd party .exe files (its a work computer). Thank you.

Comment: So yes, you can install Chrome Remote Desktop on the GCP server, and then you can connect through Chrome on your work PC. The downside to this is you need Chrome's GUI to install the remote desktop, so you'll need a 3rd-party viewer (downloading an executable). Since this is a one-time thing, you can install the remote desktop at home, then use it while at work.

Comment: Anyone coming here for this solution can use this: [https://ubuntu.com/blog/launch-ubuntu-desktop-on-google-cloud](https://ubuntu.com/blog/launch-ubuntu-desktop-on-google-cloud)